# docker-compose build Cannot find module './src'

Tags: docker, npm

I recently ran `npm install` and `npm update`.

Then I tried to build my docker container. I keep getting the same stacktrace:

```
Step 7/8 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 9d7f766e2cf7

> docs.rpg.riotgames.io@1.0.0 build /riot/rpg-docs-hub
> next build

(node:18) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Loaded env from /riot/rpg-docs-hub/.env

> Build error occurred
{ Error: Cannot find module './src'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/riot/rpg-docs-hub/node_modules/dotenv-webpack/index.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/riot/rpg-docs-hub/next.config.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! docs.rpg.riotgames.io@1.0.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the docs.rpg.riotgames.io@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-03T19_16_10_771Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'rpg-docs-hub' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried...

1. repeating `npm install` and `npm update`
2. Running `docker-compose up --build`
3. running `npm install --save-dev dotenv-webpack`, since this seems to be associated with webpack

The result is the same.

My level of technical understanding is limited, though I'm trying to ramp up quickly.

Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: What's your node version

Comment: My node version is v15.7.0.